# triple-boot in macbook Big Sur, Ubuntu, Win10 (and failed)

Tags: windows, bootcamp, partition

I'm running a MacBook Pro (13-inch, 2018, Four Thunderbolt 3 Ports). Had Ubuntu installed before (holding the options button, I can see 2 boot drives), the laptop works fine. Since I need Windows all of a sudden, I installed Windows using Bootcamp. Reboot, set up  Windows 10, complete the Bootcamp  setup in the Windows 10 system and reboot as indicated by Bootcamp, everything was fine until then.

Holding down the Option key, the Ubuntu startup drive is nowhere to be seen, but only APPLE SSD Media and Windows. I chose the Windows boot drive and it can't boot - a black screen with errors (somehow exactly the same when Ubuntu couldn't boot as I locked GRUB and didn't know how to unlock it).

Interestingly, the Ubuntu drive boots when I start the laptop without the Option key. I enter the username and password for GRUB and Ubuntu works as usual. It seems that when it is turned on, the laptop works as follows: if (not Ubuntu is true) then (MacOS is ture or Windows is ture).

Now I have unmounted the Windows partition. so it became if (not Ubuntu) then (MacOS).

My question is, I don't understand why this is happenning, also if there's a valid way of setting up a triple-boot system without the above situation occur.

Any comments helpful to the situation is appretiated.

Comment: Found out Bootcamp partition container disk 1 (APFS container) but I'm pretty sure I partitioned Ubuntu 'one level higher' on the APPLE SSD Media (CPI-expressinternal physical disk * GUID partition map). APPLE SSD Media contains container disk 1.

Comment: You could edit your question and add the output from `diskutil list`.